# Python check last word/number in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Is there a way to get python check/print the last word/number only in a string?

Here's a example of what I've got so far:

```
x = input("Input what you want to do to your number and your number: ")
if word.startswith("Pi"):
    Pi_A = x * Pi # I need x to look at the number
    print (Pi_A)
```

I need to just look at the last word/number so I can do the sum.

edit (Input/Output):

Input: ("Pi 2" is what the user inputs)

> Input what you want to do to your number and your number: Pi 2

Output: (Answer to π * 2)

> 6.2...

Comment: Post an example of input / ouput

Comment: In that code, `word` isn't defined.  What's the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
import math
x = raw_input("Input action to be peformed on your number, followed by your number: ")
# Assume "Pi 2"  is entered
x = x.split()
action = x[0]
number = int(x[1])
if action.startswith("Pi"):
    print number * math.pi
```

Execution

```
$ python j.py 
Input action to be peformed on your number, followed by your number: Pi 2
6.28318530718
```

Suggestion : Use "raw_input" instead of "input" to save quotes (also make you ready for Python 3.0 ;)

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious solution would be `str.endswith`:

```
>>> "x * Pi".endswith("Pi")
True
```

However, this would also return true if it wasn't a seperate word:

```
>>> "PiPi".endswith("Pi")
True
```

So if you want the last word in a space-separated string, you could use

```
>>> "x * Pi".split()[-1] == "Pi"
True
>>> "PiPi".split()[-1] == "Pi"
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to get the last word. and then check if the last word starts with `Pi`

```
word = text.rsplit(None, 1)[1]
if word.startswith("Pi"):
    print (x * Pi) # there is more this is just a example
```

Answer (score 2):

Say that your string is "hello2014bye2013":

The following code should do the job:

```
word = "hello2014bye2013"
alist = list(word)
print (alist[-1])
```

If you have numerous words and numbers then this should work:

```
blabla = "hello 4 my 8 name 911 is 049 Python"
lastword= blabla.split()[-1]
print (blabla)
```

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I've just added that part. Please review again :)

Comment: This might do the job. :)